# Module doesn't exist in project

Tags: android-studio, module

Why is this happening? I cannot debug or run my project in Android Studio

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hello @StonebrigeGR, instead of posting a screenshot please elaborate what problems are you facing and what did you try to get over the problem. This will help others to understand your problem and give a proper suggestion.

Comment: just tried to open my project and couldnt run it. it opened the edit configuration where there is not app project to run

Comment: someone please?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54833614/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error in [GoLand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IDEs).

**I had to delete the `.idea` folder.**

Then reopen the project, recreate the configuration and it started working.